# Kafka bootstrap-servers vs zookeeper in kafka-console-consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to test run a single Kafka node with 3 brokers & zookeeper. I wish to test using the console tools. I run the producer as such:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 --topic testTopic
```

Then I run the consumer as such:

```
kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic testTopic --from-beginning
```

And I can enter messages in the producer and see them in the consumer, as expected. **However**, when I run the updated version of the consumer using bootstrap-server, I get nothing. E.g

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 --topic testTopic --from-beginning
```

This worked fine when I had one broker running on port 9092 so I'm thoroughly confused. Is there a way I can see what zookeeper is providing as the bootstrap server? Is the bootstrap server different from the broker list? Kafka compiled with Scala 2.11.

Comment: I see the same thing. Even, after deleting log.dir. But, I don't know where is /brokers/topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea what was wrong. Likely I put Kafka or Zookeeper in a weird state. After deleting the topics in the `log.dir` of each broker AND the zookeeper topics in `/brokers/topics` then recreating the topic, Kafka consumer behaved as expected.

Comment: Where's the /broker/topics?

Comment: I found it with zookeeper-shell <zookeeper_host:zookeeper:port> and then issue the command: rmr /brokers/topics/TOPIC_NAME You can type help in zookeeper-shell to see the commands. Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073955/kafka-consumer-with-new-api-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap servers are same as kafka brokers. And if you want to see the list of bootstrap server zookeeper is providing,  you can query ZNode information via any ZK client. All active brokers are registered under /brokers/ids/[brokerId]. All you need is zkQuorum address. Below command will give you
list of active bootstrap servers :

./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when using mismatched versions of:

- Kafka client libraries
- Kafka scripts
- Kafka brokers

In my exact scenario I was using Confluent Kafka client libraries version 0.10.2.1 with Confluent Platform 3.3.0 w/ Kafka broker 0.11.0.0.  When I downgraded my Confluent Platform to 3.3.2 which matched my client libraries the consumer worked as expected.

My theory is that the latest kafka-console-consumer using the new Consumer API was only retrieving messages using the latest format.  There were a number of message format changes introduced in Kafka 0.11.0.0.