# Kafka consumer with new API not working

Tags: apache-kafka

I found something very weird with Kafka.

I have a producer with 3 brokers :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093, localhost:9094, localhost:9095 --topic topic
```

Then I try to run a consumer with the new API :

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093,localhost:9094,localhost:9095 --topic topic --from-beginning
```

I got nothing ! BUT if I use the old API :

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning --topic topic
```

I got my messages !

What is wrong with me ?

PS : I am using Kafka 10

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `--bootstrap-server` only takes a single `host:port` and not a list? Also, you might need to add `--new-consumer`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It tried what you propose but didn't work. I eventually resolve my problem (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually resolved my problem thanks to this similar post : [Kafka bootstrap-servers vs zookeeper in kafka-console-consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774446/kafka-bootstrap-servers-vs-zookeeper-in-kafka-console-consumer)

I believe it is a bug / wrong configuration of mine leading to a problem with zookeeper and kafka.

**SOLUTION :**

First be sure to have enable topic deleting in `server.properties` files of your brokers :

```
# Switch to enable topic deletion or not, default value is false
delete.topic.enable=true
```

Then delete the topic :

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic myTopic
```

Remove all the `/tmp/log.dir` directories of your brokers.

**EDIT** : I faced again the problem and I had to remove also the log files of zookeeper in `/tmp/zookeeper/version-2/`.

Finally delete the topic in `/brokers/topics` in zookeeper as follow :

```
$ kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

rmr /broker/topics/mytopic
```

And restart your brokers and create your topic again.

Comment: That solved for me, great! However, what about this in production? If we should not delete topics?

Comment: I don't think this makes it an answer, as no root has been provided, rather simple and specific setup steps.

Answer (score 0):

After fighting a while with same problem. Specify `--partition`  and console consumer new API works (but hangs..). I have CDH 5.12 + Kafka 0.11 (from parcel).

UPD:

Also find out that Kafka 0.11 (versioned as 3.0.0 in CDH parclel) does not work correctly with consuming messages. After downgrading to Kafka 0.10 it become OK. `--partition` does not need any more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I was using a single broker instance for my "cluster", and I was getting this error:

**/var/log/messages**

```
[2018-04-04 22:29:39,854] ERROR [KafkaApi-20] Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

I just added in my server configuration file the setting `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1` and restarted. It started to work fine.