# Consuming and Producing Kafka messages on different servers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

How can I produce and consume messages from different servers? 
I tried the Quickstart tutorial, but there is no instructions on how to setup for multi server clusters.

My Steps 
Server A 
1)`bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` 
2)`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties` 
3)`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 
   1 --partitions 1 --topic test` 
4)`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list SERVER-a.IP:9092 --topic test`

Server B 
1A)`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server SERVER-a.IP:9092 --topic 
   test --from-beginning` 
1B)`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server SERVER-a.IP:2181 --topic 
   test --from-beginning`

When I run **1A)** consumer and enter messages into the producer, there is no messages appearing in the consumer. Its just blank.  
When I run **1B** consumer instead, I get a huge & very fast stream of error logs in Server A until I Ctrl+C the consumer. **See below** 
**Error log on Server A** streaming at hundreds per second 
`WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)`
`O Closed socket connection for client /188.166.178.40:51168 (no session established for client) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to have your producer on Server A and your consumer on server B, you are in the right direction.

You need to run a Broker on server A to make it work.

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

The other commands are correct.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I've added my full problem explanation in my question. Can get your help see where is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem for 1B) is that you can't run a consumer with zookeeper address for `--bootstrap-server` option. That is why you get these errors.
Concerning 1A), I faced this problem sometimes. Take a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43092572/5035392. It could resolve your problem.

Comment: Also, try this command for the producer : `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper SERVER-a:2181 --from-beginning --topic test`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a similar topic for kafka-steams application, it appears that multiple kafka cluster is not supported yet:

Here is a documentation from kafka: https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#bootstrap-servers

**bootstrap.servers**

(Required) The Kafka bootstrap servers. This is the same setting that is used by the underlying producer and consumer clients to connect to the Kafka cluster. `Example: "kafka-broker1:9092,kafka-broker2:9092".`

Tip:

> Kafka Streams applications can only communicate with a single Kafka
> cluster specified by this config value. Future versions of Kafka
> Streams will support connecting to different Kafka clusters for
> reading input streams and writing output streams.