# Is Zookeeper use deprecated in Kafka last versions?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

For long time, Kafka is trying to get rid of Zookeeper.
Is Zookeeper use deprecated for Kafka last versions? 
Or it is still required for a Kafka cluster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap server vs zookeeper in kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173003/bootstrap-server-vs-zookeeper-in-kafka)

Comment: For more details about ZK removal, you can watch this Kafka Summit talk that explains KIP-500: https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-san-francisco-2019/kafka-neeads-no-keeper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[KIP 500](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum) is for removing Zookeeper dependency. Currently the newest version of Kafka has not removed it. You can view the list of KIP and the version of Kafka that implements them [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Improvement+Proposals?src=breadcrumbs-parent). No Kafka version is specified for KIP 500.